# Generic String Setting via CSS / SASS

Tags: css, sass

Is there some type of value that can be assigned any arbitrary string using CSS? For example, `"large"` or `"small"`.

My purpose is to watch a generic `div` with `display: none` and change this as-of-yet-unknown type of value `"large"` or `"small"` via a media query. Javascript will watch for this change and use the assigned value.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="state"/>
```

Example corresponding SASS:

```
.state {
    @media #{$isSmall} {
        unknown-type-of-value: "small";
    }
    @media #{$isLarge} {
        unknown-type-of-value: "large";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, can you elaborate and perhaps post some code?

Comment: Do you mean like `.element:after{ content:"state1"; }`?

Comment: At Stack Overflow, it is our sole purpose to help you as much as possible. However, this site is for help with trying to fix your code, not giving you code. If you want people to help you, then it would be appreciated to have some evidence of research

Comment: I think this is pretty clear now, Marcin and Andrew Barber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the value of a `<div>` with CSS, but you can use `:after` to have css "append" text to it.

Something like

```
@media screen{
    div.test:after{
        content: "small";
    }

}

@media print{
    div.test:after{
        content: "large";
    }

}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/edirad/1 (try to print it, and look at the preview)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to understand my question.

Comment: Actually, I tested setting content directly and it appears to work, at least on Chrome.